# PHP Session Limits mySQL queries for users?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a PHP app I've developed. I've noticed that if I use the app in multiple windows, using the same session, and if one window is busy doing a significant mySql task, on the other window, it won't complete until the first window is done running it's queries.  I'm assuming there is a limit to the number of queries per user session that is allowed, and that there is a setting in PHP to allow a single session to use multiple windows or queries, but I can't seem to find it.   Could you anyone point me in the right direction?  Tried Googling it, but wasn't able to figure out the correct way to phrase the search.

Thanks!

Comment: it's a browser thing..

Comment: create a session id of the logged user, save it in the data base and then validate the session of the user upon loging in and using multiple windows. if the session id dont match with the current user and the window, php will flag the user.   it is the same solution with multiple logins of the same user on different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) ?

Basically, when a connection is made to a PHP script, PHP locks the session (for writing purposes), and any other requests to that session are queued (to prevent any unexpected errors while writing to session simultaneously from different PHP scripts)

And session is locked until the PHP script is executed, thus MySQL task is basically clogging the session queue.

Just tell PHP that you won't be writing to the session anymore, right before performing the actual task.

```
<?php

session_start();
$user = $_SESSION["user"];

// you did your thing, now leave the session
session_write_close();

// some clogging task
while ($i < 10) {
    sleep(1);
    $i++;
}
```